# Rails App trying to use mongodb when I've never used mongodb ever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

So my app was working fine until I restarted my computer and tried to run "rails server" to get my server up and running again. Instead, I get the following errors:

```
/Users/janedoe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': 

Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/mongodb_adapter'. 
Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. 
If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 
'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile. (LoadError)
```

Anyways, I've *never* used mongodb with my application in my entire life. (I use postgres) I don't know why it's asking me to use that adapter. The only thing I can think of is that I installed mongodb using homebrew for a separate project that has nothing to do with Rails. I don't know if maybe after installing it changed some of my things around for some weird, inexplicable reason.

Here is my database.yml file

```
development: 
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

I'm not sure *at all* why it's trying to use mongodb_adapter. I dont have that specified anywhere, I haven't told it to ever use mongodb, I don't understand at all why this is happening....

Comment: Try to do `bundle install` then `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` . What is the output ?

Comment: Ok, I did a `bundle install` followed by a `rake db:migrate` and got the same error as above. for some reason it's ignoring my config file altogether?

Comment: but did you run whole command what i posted above ? Not just `db:migrate` ?

Comment: I don't want to drop my entire database, there's way too much valuable data in there for me to just drop like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31544547/rake-tasks-seem-to-ignore-database-yml-configuration). It seems like there is a link in the bash_profile which affects the Rails database configurations.

Comment: thank you!! I think this is exactly what is wrong, I have a DATABASE_URL defined for another app in my environment variables.