# Rails app using docker-compose wont connect to the mysql container

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

Trying to get a rails app running using docker-compose. I run docker-compose build and it completes with no errors. I then  run docker-compose up and both of the containers start. Then I run docker-compose run web rake db:create db:migrate and run into an error:

rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111 "Connection refused")

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.3
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs mysql-client sqlite3 zlib1g-dev libxslt-dev git  && \
gem install bundler
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /myapp
```

Docker-compose

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'online_community_development'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '******'
      MYSQL_HOST: 'localhost'
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      # Opens port 3306 on the container
      - '3306'
      # Where our data will be persisted
    volumes:
      - 'my-db:/var/lib/mysql'
    container_name: datab




  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
    - web-app:/myapp
    ports:
    - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
    - db
    links:
      - db:db
    restart: always

volumes:
  my-db: {}
  web-app: {}
```

Database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: online_community_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: slumland
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  host: db
```

New to docker so not even sure if I am issuing the commands correctly. I need to create and seed the database and have the app container connect to it. I think the issue is related to it trying to connect via localhost, but even when I changed the host to db I still got the same results. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tl;dr:
Try this `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'online_community_development'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '******'
      MYSQL_HOST: 'localhost'
    expose:
    # Opens port 3306 on the container
      - '3306'
    # Where our data will be persisted
    volumes:
      - 'my-db:/var/lib/mysql'
    container_name: datab

  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: 'mysql2://db'
      RAILS_ENV: 'development'
    volumes:
    - web-app:/myapp
    ports:
    - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
    - db
    restart: always

volumes:
  my-db: {}
  web-app: {}
```

In detail:
First of all your `docker-compose`-file is kinda misconfigured.
Therefore I will do a small instruction on `docker-compose.yml`-files before heading over to your question.

The `links:`-thing is a legacy feature of `docker` which you should strictly avoid:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links
Moreover, it is not even required when you're working with `docker-compose`

Also, you're using `expose:` and `ports:` when defining your database-service.
The `ports`-key is opening up a port on your host-machine and forwards it to your docker-service:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports
Using `ports`-key on database-definitions makes your database accessible to the www - which is not what you want in most cases.

The `expose`-key opens the port locally, in the created docker network.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#expose
This is what we want for databases.

Editing your `docker-compose.yml`-file results in the following:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'online_community_development'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '******'
      MYSQL_HOST: 'localhost'
    expose:
    # Opens port 3306 on the container
      - '3306'
    # Where our data will be persisted
    volumes:
      - 'my-db:/var/lib/mysql'
    container_name: datab

  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
    - web-app:/myapp
    ports:
    - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
    - db
    restart: always

volumes:
  my-db: {}
  web-app: {}
```

Getting back to your primary problem:
`rake aborted! Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111 "Connection refused")`

It looks like `rake` expects the database to be available at `localhost` - therefore I think that the cause of this issue is a misconfiguration.
Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with `rake` but nevertheless your `database.yaml` looks correct.
I did some research and came across this post:
[Rake tasks seem to ignore database.yml configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31544547/rake-tasks-seem-to-ignore-database-yml-configuration)
Maybe you could try to set the environment-variable `DATABASE_URL` in your `docker-compose`-file: `DATABASE_URL=mysql://db`
I'd also recommend to set the correct context-environment-variable: `RAILS_ENV=development`

When you do alle these changes you should come up with the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'online_community_development'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '******'
      MYSQL_HOST: 'localhost'
    expose:
    # Opens port 3306 on the container
      - '3306'
    # Where our data will be persisted
    volumes:
      - 'my-db:/var/lib/mysql'
    container_name: datab

  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: 'mysql2://db'
      RAILS_ENV: 'development'
    volumes:
    - web-app:/myapp
    ports:
    - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
    - db
    restart: always

volumes:
  my-db: {}
  web-app: {}
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Hermsi

Comment: Thank you !! Clear explanation and links as someone new to docker it is greatly appreciated. Made the changes you suggested and finally got it working.

Comment: Hey @YungFlizzy, I'm glad that your application is behaving as expected now!
Maybe you could mark my answer as "accepted". Thank you and have a good day. (:

Answer (score -1):

your db seems to be configured to listen on localhost only. Unfortunately this will not work since your app is technically another network host (container) within the compose network. Try making your db listen on all network interfaces.